# PHP code to present information from RIPE XML file

Tags: php, xml, lookup, whois

Here is a tool for WHOIS lookups that I use: http://apps.db.ripe.net/search/lookup.html

It can present information in an XML file, like this: http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/192.36.171.155.xml

Let's say I wanted to read the XML file by using PHP and present the **netname** and **descr** fields in an HTML document, how would I do that?

Comment: Is it still working? I have tested it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). Once you've loaded the file it's easy to traverse...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/192.36.171.155.xml');
echo $xml->objects->object->attributes->attribute[1]->attributes()->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you searched [PHP XML Parser on Google](http://www.google.fr/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+XML+parser) ?